# Как управлять url в bitrix?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, битрикс, redirect, http-redirect

В меню обработки адресов в битриксе, по пути
Обработка адресов-> Правила обработки
Находится панель подмены физического адреса.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как версию domain.ru/ru/, перенаправить
в domain.ru исходя из следующей строки кода

```
#^(ru|en)/about/news/([a-z]+-[a-z]+)\.php#
#^/(ru|en)/download(.*)$#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу, вам требуется *перенаправление* -- то есть 301-й редирект. Это *не настраивается* через "Правила обработки адресов", поэтому вам придется править `.htaccess`. Есть [тема на форуме Битрикса об этом](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic27330/).
Вам также, скорее всего, надо будет правильно настроить языковые настройки: `/bitrix/admin/lang_admin.php?lang=ru`